# Symfony2 custom validator as service not loaded

Tags: symfony, validation

**EDIT : SOLVED**

I'm trying to build a custom validator running as a service (mainly for getting the entity manager).

I followed the doc and some blog posts but can't make it working.
I don't get any error message but the method isValid from my constraint is never called.

**My Entity class (that has to be validated by "UniqueLem" (note that the Doctrine validator works):**

```
namespace Elyotech\VersionManagerBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Me\AdminBundle\Validator\UniqueLem;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Me\VersionManagerBundle\Repository\ProjectRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="project")
 * @UniqueLem
 * @UniqueEntity("name")
 */
class Project{...
```

**My Constraint class:**
namespace Elyotech\AdminBundle\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

```
/*
 * @Annotation
 * */

class UniqueLem extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'This value is already used';
    public $entity;
    public $property;

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        die; // Test to check if function is called
        return 'validator.unique';
    }

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
```

**Validator**

```
    namespace Elyotech\AdminBundle\Validator;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class UniqueValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct( $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function isValid($value, Constraint $constraint) {
        $this->setMessage($constraint->message);
        return false;
    }
```

**Service declaration:**

```
 my.validator.unique:
   class:      %my.validator.unique.class%
   arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
   tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: validator.unique }
```

So the issue doesn't seem to be coming from the service as I never reach the "die" in the UniqueLem/isValid() function.

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved!
It was simply the PHPDoc comment form annotation that wasn't correct.
Should have been (not the asterisk):
/*
 * @Annotation
 * /

Comment: You should post this as an answer and mark it as accepted.  Much easier to see what solved it that way rather than editing the question.

Comment: As it's too localized i would suggest to delete te question.

Comment: The question is very usefull, why to delete it @gremo? Please add an answer, it is easier to understand than a comment.